# Adding a '|' character to a case statement in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, switch-statement

I have the following case statement in a stored procedure:

```
Position    = case coalesce(teamMember.JobTitle, '')  when '' then '' else '<b>' + coalesce(teamMember.JobTitle, '') + '</b>' end
                                + isnull(teamMember.OrganizationNameLevel1, '')
                                + case when isnull(teamMember.OrganizationNameLevel2, '') <> isnull(teamMember.OrganizationNameLevel1, '') THEN ' | ' + isnull(teamMember.OrganizationNameLevel2, '') ELSE '' END
                                + case when isnull(teamMember.OrganizationNameLevel3, '') <> isnull(teamMember.OrganizationNameLevel2, '') THEN ' | ' + isnull(teamMember.OrganizationNameLevel3, '') ELSE '' END 
                                + case when isnull(teamMember.OrganizationNameLevel4, '') <> isnull(teamMember.OrganizationNameLevel3, '') THEN ' | ' + isnull(teamMember.OrganizationNameLevel4, '') ELSE '' END
                                + case when isnull(teamMember.OrganizationNameLevel5, '') <> isnull(teamMember.OrganizationNameLevel4, '') THEN ' | ' + isnull(teamMember.OrganizationNameLevel5, '') ELSE '' END
                                + case when isnull(teamMember.OrganizationNameLevel6, '') <> isnull(teamMember.OrganizationNameLevel5, '') THEN ' | ' + isnull(teamMember.OrganizationNameLevel6, '') ELSE '' END,
```

It produces the following result:

```
<b>APPS SYSTEMS ENGINEER</b>TECH & OPS | ENT INFO TECH | DEP & OPS TECH | HR SYS & ITECH | COMP & BEN APPS
```

What I need is for it to show is this:

```
**<b>APPS SYSTEMS ENGINEER</b> |** TECH & OPS | ENT INFO TECH | DEP & OPS TECH | HR SYS & ITECH | COMP & BEN APPS
```

Comment: Tag the dbms used. (And that's case expressions, not case statements.)

Comment: It is tagged as SQL. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @HughVeal something like [tag:sql-server] or [tag:oracle] or [tag:mysql]

Comment: SQL stands for the SQL language, as specified by ANSI/ISO. Perhaps you mean sql-server, as in Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: @HughVeal the SQL in SqlServer, Oracle, MySql etc all have specific features/quirks, not found in others.

Comment: @HughVeal sql server, oracle, mysql...which brand and version of DB are you using?

Comment: Can't you just change `+ '</b>'` to `+ '</b> | '` ?

Comment: @jarlh...I added the sql-server tag.

Comment: @jpw....I tried '</b > |', but it does not work.

Comment: This is for SQL Server 2012.

Comment: @HughVeal - Please expand on `it does not work` *(the singularly most useless phrase I see on SO)*.  What results are you seeing?  Please show the exact SQL used, the data going in, the results you get out and the results you expect.  Or, in the event of an error message, the exact SQL and the exact error message.

Comment: @HughVeal Can you be more specific? In what way didn't it work?

Comment: {Position = case coalesce(teamMember.JobTitle, '')  when '' then '' else '<b>' + coalesce(teamMember.JobTitle, '') + '</b> | ' end
       + isnull(teamMember.OrganizationNameLevel1, '')
        + case when isnull(teamMember.OrganizationNameLevel2, '')...}     
Produces the result:   <b>APPS SYSTEMS ENGINEER</b>TECH & OPS | ENT INFO TECH | DEP & OPS TECH | HR SYS & ITECH | COMP & BEN APPS

Comment: @MatBailie...All of that is included in the original post above.

Comment: The result should look like: <b>APPS SYSTEMS ENGINEER</b> | TECH & OPS | ENT INFO TECH | DEP & OPS TECH | HR SYS & ITECH | COMP & BEN APPS

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be as simple as:

```
Position = case coalesce(teamMember.JobTitle, '')  when '' then '' else '<b>' + coalesce(teamMember.JobTitle, '') + '</b>' end
  + isnull(' | ' + teamMember.OrganizationNameLevel1, '')  --<-- add a Pipe here inside the ISNULL function 
  + case when isnull(teamMember.OrganizationNameLevel2, '') <> isnull(teamMember.OrganizationNameLevel1, '') THEN ' | ' + isnull(teamMember.OrganizationNameLevel2, '') ELSE '' END
  + .........
```

Comment: @M.Ali.....I added the pipe there as you suggested, but it does not produce the pipe in the result.

Comment: Here is something very weird. When I run a query with this case expression, it adds the '|' character as I would like. But when I run the stored procedure with the EXACT same '|' pipe, it does not show in the result.

Comment: @HughVeal you need to track down the first value in string, where is it comming from? then look in your code and see why it is not prefixed with a pipe, its impossible for anyone on this platform to help you with this with having access to the underlying data you are working with.